# How can I fix this ImportError?

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error

```
ImportError: no module named request
```

To fix this:

```
sudo apt-get install request
```

works in Ubuntu. How do I fix this error in CentOS?

Comment: Just what *request* are you installing through apt-get?  And what does *works* mean in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [pip from source](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-from-source). Then try

```
pip install django-request
```

Comment: Yes it is perfect for ubuntu, but not for centos

Comment: Why not? Any problems?

Comment: when i am trying to install the package request in cent os, 'yum install request' is not installing the package. "Deprecation Error" occurs

Comment: You need to install [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-from-source) first and then install [django-request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-request) using pip.

Comment: Yes arul, whatever u are saying is perfect for other os, but giving error for cent os

Comment: "pip" command is provided by the [package pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/1.5.6). This can be installed using the "easy_install" command. If CentOS have not it, you can install using [this instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions)

Answer (score 1):

1. yum install python-setuptools
2. easy_install install pip
3. pip install requests